# telnet://IP from Firefox and Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, telnet, xdg-open

I have a problem initiating telnet sessions (`telnet://IP`) from Firefox and Chrome.

- With Chrome I have the following problem: When I click the telnet link, appears the "External Protocol Request" prompt with `xdg-open` but when I click "Launch Application" nothing happens.
- In Firefox's case I followed the tutorial bellow and mere, but also when clicking telnet links nothing happens.
  [Ubuntu 14.04 Mozilla Firefox Telnet Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572751/ubuntu-14-04-mozilla-firefox-telnet-error)

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 and latest version of Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Do you try [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ipprotocols/?src=search) add-on for mozilla?

Comment: I know this one. It is a nice add-on but it is not what I am familiar with. I am in transition from windows to Ubuntu and this is a thing that I use every day.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide us with which answers you tried on the duplicate question you linked to and what your results were.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just 'telnet' with the command line?

Comment: Which program to use for Telnet?

Comment: I used to use Putty

Comment: I second @ThomasW. Why can't you just use the included `telnet` command/program?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure why you're using `telnet` via a web browser - it makes little sense to do this.  So, we need to use an actual telnet command rather than hack away at Firefox to make it work with 'telnet'.

---

You stated in comments you used to use PuTTY for telnet..  PuTTY actually exists in the repositories and you can use it.  This command installs it: `sudo apt-get install putty`

You would then run it from the dash panel on Unity.

---

There is also an available `telnet` program in the repositories, and it should be installed by default.  `telnet` gives you a `telnet` interface via the command line and ONLY the telnet interface (you run it from inside of the Terminal).  You can install it by `sudo apt-get install telnet` if your system says it is not installed.  (This means you won't need PuTTY which looks odd on *nix in the way it formats things, and would work with the terminal in a better way, so this is the suggested method to telnet.)

Comment: Pretty sure `telnet` comes standard.

Comment: @Seth updated to include that it's supposed to be installed by default (I checked the manifest of the images, just to confirm) but if it says it's not then you have the command there to install it.

Comment: I happen to manage 300 switches that are monitored via a web interface so I constantly have at least 2 - 3 consoles opened. The problem is that I can't remember the IP's or hostnames to manually telnet to the switches so it is more simpler to click a little icon and i'm in.

Comment: @NovelliNorbert And the web interface uses *telnet*?  How old are these switches?  What brand/model?  And why don't you keep documentation on hostnames/IPs like you should be doing?

Answer (score 1):

I answer to an almost 10 years old question for two reasons:

- I had an dormant **Ask Ubuntu** account for quite a while and I just want to try out.
- I had the same question around the time you raised your's. After I figured out a clumsy solution on my own and posted it someone hinted me to a better one. Unfortunately I lost the link to that blog post ...

At that time I considered it as a valid use case. I had a script which scanned lab devices and presented open tcp ports 22 and 23 within a web page with urls telnet://... respectively ssh://...
Even though I lost the link to my original blog post I still have the 'reminder' script in my vault - maybe someone might find this inspiring ...

## in bash

```
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ssh/command '/usr/bin/moz-ssh.sh %s' --type String
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ssh/enabled --type Boolean true
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ssh/needs_terminal --type Boolean true
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/telnet/command '/usr/bin/moz-telnet.sh %s' --type String
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/telnet/enabled --type Boolean true
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/telnet/needs_terminal --type Boolean true
```

## create script

```
echo "#!/usr/bin/bash" > /usr/bin/moz-telnet.sh
echo "address=\`echo \$1 | cut -d / -f 3\`" >> /usr/bin/moz-telnet.sh
echo "port=\`echo \$1 | cut -d / -f 4\`" >> /usr/bin/moz-telnet.sh
echo "if [ \"\$port\" == \"\" ]; then" >> /usr/bin/moz-telnet.sh
echo "   port=23" >> /usr/bin/moz-telnet.sh
echo "fi" >> /usr/bin/moz-telnet.sh
echo "putty -telnet \${address} -P \${port}" >> /usr/bin/moz-telnet.sh
echo "#!/bin/bash" > /usr/bin/moz-ssh.sh
echo "address=\`echo \$1 | cut -d / -f 3\`" >> /usr/bin/moz-ssh.sh
echo "port=\`echo \$1 | cut -d / -f 4\`" >> /usr/bin/moz-ssh.sh
echo "if [ "\$port" == "" ]; then" >> /usr/bin/moz-ssh.sh
echo "   port=22" >> /usr/bin/moz-ssh.sh
echo "fi" >> /usr/bin/moz-ssh.sh
echo "putty -ssh \${address} -P \${port}" >> /usr/bin/moz-ssh.sh
chmod 755 /usr/bin/moz-telnet.sh
chmod 755 /usr/bin/moz-ssh.sh
```

## in firefox about:config

```
network.protocol-handler.expose.telnet;false
network.protocol-handler.expose.ssh;false
```

## infirefox 55 and later

$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/XXXXXXXXX.default/handlers.json:

```
... ,"ssh":{"action":2,"handlers":[{"name":"moz-ssh.sh","path":"/usr/bin/moz-ssh.sh"}]},"telnet":{"action":2,"handlers":[{"name":"moz-telnet.sh","path":"/usr/bin/moz-telnet.sh"}]} ...
```

Please don't throw keyboards at me ;-) - this worked for me in the former days but it is not tested on current versions of ubuntu and firefox.

Cheers!

Joerg